# Python WSS: chrome not recognizing auto validated certificate

Tags: python, macos, sockets, ssl, websocket

I have a webapp (**client**) and a daemon (**server**) running on my local machine and they share messages. Everything works fine when not using secure socket.

I am trying to implement WSS now, but chrome continues to refuse the certificate I have generated with `openssl`:

```
webSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:8190/Action
failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

What I've tried so far:

- I have tried adding my `.crt` file in Apple `KeyChain` in both `System`and `Login`
- I have tried generating a new certificate and do everything again.

For websockets I am using **[this library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websockets)**, and this is how I am opening the socket:

```
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile='/localhost.crt')
st_server = websockets.serve(self.__on_receive, 'localhost', '8190',
                                 ssl=ssl_context)
```

Any help, reference to relevant documentation would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I've changed the above code to this:

```
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
ssl_context.load_cert_chain(os.path.join('/', "localhost.crt"),
                            os.path.join('/', "localhost.key"))
st_server = websockets.serve(self.__on_receive, 'localhost', '8190',
                                     ssl=ssl_context)
```

Basically I was not loading the certs correctly.